# Is this LDO instability a real problem or a model bug?

Tags: power-supply, ltspice, feedback, ldo, stability

Here is an LTSPICE simulation for which I just have an LDO ([ADP7118](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adp7118.pdf)) in its recommended environment and some reasonable parasitics.  It is unstable as you can see in the transient plot (showing the LDO Vin's chip voltage, separated from the 10V battery by a 100nH parasitic line inductance; Vout similarly rings about 5V).  Why?  Is this a common issue with LDOs?  By the way, I simulated two other LDO chips but could not cause a similar instability.

[image: schematic]
[image: transient]

Comment: 10nH is huge for a closely mounted SMD MLCC. But generally, I wouldn't trust oscillations beyond approximately 10 MHz to be accurately modelled because such parasitics are hardly accurate in a basic spice component model. I am sure this is a sim/GIGO issue.

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you about this device's instability issues? What does the data sheet tell you about minimum loading on the output? What does it tell you about the range of output capacitor values that are valid? Have you examined the voltage after inductor L5 to see if your circuit invalidates the requirements for the device? Why is the plot showing 10 volts as the average voltage when it's a 5 volt regulator? Are you sure you are showing the correct graph? Names nodes with labels and use labels to plot graphs.

Comment: @Andyaka I added some details to my question to clarify it.  My layout parasitics might be a little high, but are not ridiculously high...I think a lawyer could argue that I meet all datasheet requirements.  Of course, I am pushing limits here because I want to understand the instability theory (not the best layout practice).

Comment: But, you are not showing the right graph. Please properly read my earlier comment

Comment: What is the oscillation frequency, and what is the battery ESR at this frequency?

Comment: @TimWilliams As noted in my schematic above, the oscillation period is 2 ns (it appears to be a 10nH*10pF resonance).  The battery is an ideal LTSPICE voltage source, so it has zero ESR (more ESR here does not help, by the way).

Comment: How have you determined 10pF in the model? At this point it seems a modeling issue (erroneous analysis settings, or the part model itself), and contacting the manufacturer is appropriate. Let us know what you find.

Comment: @TimWilliams "C4 1 6 10p" written in the "ADP7102.lib" file.  (Of course, I first deduced that 10nH was crucial by varying it and then re-running, and then I deduced that 10pF was the critical capacitance by using the resonance frequency, and then I searched for this in the file.)

Answer (score 1):

The frequency of 0.5 GHz is far outside the bandwidth of the regulator..It is purely due to the passives that you have specced and those which have been vaguely tossed into the model.

These form an LCR resonator. The frequency will be even higher when you use a lower and more realistic ESL. In that case, the Q will also be lower (i.e. more damped).

Now in reality such high frequency oscillations at GHz are even more strongly damped than is evident in spice because:

- the component model likely isn't very accurate at beyond-BW frequencies
- there are loss mechanisms from stray coupling into surrounding material, dielectric losses and eddy current losses
- not much energy is being pumped into the passive resonator at these GHz frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Instability in LDOs is a real problem.

In a conventional linear regulator, which uses an n-type (npn bjt or n-channel fet) pass transistor, the loop gain is low and it's relatively difficult to get the control system to oscillate.

In a low-dropout regulator, which uses a p-type (pnp bjt or p-channel fet) pass transistor, the loop gain is higher, which makes the system more prone to oscillations. They frequently have strict requirements on the output capacitor to prevent oscillation.

In particular, the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP7118.pdf) of the ADP7118 that you're using specifies ("capacitor selection" section on page 14) a minimum of 2.2 μF output capacitance with an ESR no greater than 0.3 Ω. While it would appear you've met this requirement, you have also included an equivalent series *inductance* that's orders of magnitude higher than a realistic MLCC, and which could easily destabilize the control loop.

Using Murata's SimSurfing tool, I found a representative capacitor--an 0603 2.2 μF X7R rated for 6.3 V--and looked at its inductance vs frequency graph:
[image]

As you can see, this capacitor's ESL is much closer to 0.3 nH than the 10 nH you're using in your simulation. Even with a fairly poor PCB layout, I wouldn't expect anywhere near 10 nH in series with the output capacitor. 1 nH would be a more reasonable number.

I suspect this is what's causing your problem.

Comment: I agree, a good layout would probably have about 1 nH total to each capacitor, but I was thinking 10 nH is a nice safe margin for design.  Anyway, the heart of my question:  Do you think 10 nH causes a real instability or just a model bug instability?

Comment: Actually, bondwire inductance inside the IC package could be 5 nH and I don't see any simple L component in its LTSPICE behavioral model...  Let me just take the 10 nH as given for the sake of my instability theory question.

Comment: @bobuhito Bondwire inductance will be accounted for in a good model of the part. What model of the ADP7118 are you using? To my knowledge, the model provided by AD is encrypted, so you certainly won't be able to see any simple components in there.

Comment: As you can see in the schematic above, model is "ADP7118-5.0".  It is not encrypted and can be read inside the "ADP7102.lib" file.

Comment: Note that component inductance is measured at the pads, in an RF fixture. It is not representative of stray inductance in a real layout, which is determined by the lengths of vias, traces, component body, and pins in a given loop.  10nH is a somewhat large but not unreasonable value for a somewhat loose layout.

Comment: I disagree that 0.5 GHz has anything to do with tentative loop instability of LDOs.

Answer (score -1):

you can have a simialr effect on AD7112-5 . But you should Avoid C2 Self resonnance frequency (SRF)  @ Vsense pin.
You could add a parallel Resitance to C2 (any value would be acceptable )
[image]

Comment: Your circuit is stable (the ringing dies out), so it does not surprise me like ADP7118 does.